# Shower thoughts

Tags: visual, rebus

What is the image below trying to say?

$\hskip1in$[image: winniethepooh]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It says

> SHAMPOO

because

> the bear is called [POOH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnie-the-Pooh), and there's a sign on him saying FAKE (aka SHAM), hence FAKE POOH or shampoo.

This also fits the title, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Cf. https://msh210.tumblr.com/post/39992000044

Comment: @msh210 Yeah, it's a joke I'd also thought of before ;-)